# JSF 2.0 f:setPropertyActionListener

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to nest multiple `setPropertyActionListener`'s in my commandLink but only one works.  How do you attempt this? This command link sets properties and then opens a dialog so its basically initializing the dialog.

How is this accomplished?

```
<p:commandLink update=":dreamWebSearchFrm" value="#{bundle['dreamModify.search.link.TEXT']}" oncomplete="webSearchDlg.show()">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="false" target="#{dreamSearchBean.shouldRender}"/>
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="true" target="#{dreamSearchBean.shouldRender1}"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could make use of EL parameters and call a single method on your bean. From that method, update whatever you want.

e.g.

```
#{dreamSearchBean.shouldRenderInit(false, true)}
```

In your bean:

```
public void shouldRenderInit(boolean one, boolean two) {
    setShouldRender(one);
    setShouldRender1(two);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try with

```
<p:commandLink update=":dreamWebSearchFrm" value="#{bundle['dreamModify.search.link.TEXT']}" oncomplete="webSearchDlg.show()">
   <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{false}" target="#{dreamSearchBean.shouldRender}"/>
   <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{true}" target="#{dreamSearchBean.shouldRender1}"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

It is correct with JSF 1.2 and richfaces.

Answer (score -1):

I use the following command to set property value

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener
        target="#{facRwMappingListBean.facRwMapping.finalActionCdDesc}"
    value="#{gridData.finalActionCdDesc}" />
```

Mine is working fine. Your code looks correct except the value="true" part. Try to pass boolean value in the following way.

```
value=#{"true"}
```